# How can I show map from GeoServer using JavaScript on my web with base map OpenLayers?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/flood/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=flood%3Apak_water_areas_dcw&bbox=61.2723655700684%2C23.694694519043%2C75.8473587036133%2C36.5595054626465&width=768&height=677&srs=EPSG%3A404000&format=application/openlayers

How can I show  map from GeoServer using JavaScript on my web with base map OpenLayers?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-no-proj.html (or if you are using a full build 
https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/wms-no-proj.html)

You would need to replace

```
  code: 'EPSG:21781',
```

with

```
  code: 'EPSG:404000',
```

Decide whether to use either a tile layer or an image layer (delete the other from the layers array) and set the source options to

```
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/flood/wms',
  params: {'VERSION': '1.1.0', 'LAYERS': 'flood:Apak_water_areas_dcw'},
  serverType: 'geoserver'
```

Finally set the view center to a value more appropriate for your bbox and increase the zoom a bit

```
      center: [68, 30],
      projection: projection,
      zoom: 14
```